# I can't figure out my Python Socket error

Tags: python, sockets

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt     HTTP/1.0\n\n')

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
        break
    print data;

mysock.close()
```

---

**[Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed**
I can't figure what is my fault. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the path from the domain you're trying to connect to:

```
mysock.connect('www.pythonlearn.com', 80)
```